# Where is the Sharepoint 2010 media web part

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I want to add video to my SharePoint 2010 site but I can't find the video and Audio web part

Can someone help?

Answer (score 8):

Media Web Part is included in Publishing feature, which is only available in SharePoint Server 2010. You won't have it if you're using SharePoint foundation.

If you do have this, activate the publishing feature on your site and you should see it.

Good FAQ here

[FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sanjaynarang/archive/2010/05/26/media-web-part-in-sharepoint-2010-faq.aspx)

Best of luck,
Shane

Comment: Thanks alot I activate the feature and now i see it